# Problem with SQL Server Select Replace()

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

I am successfully executing the following query in SQL Server 2008 built into VS2008:

```
SELECT REPLACE(image32, 'img', 'images/Products')
FROM Product
```

but when I do a `select * from product` query, I am given the old results. Whats going on?  Why isnt my data being updated?

Did I just answer my question?  Do I need to throw in an Update statement as well?  If so, can you help me, my sql nerd powers are not that great yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example update statement:

```
UPDATE Product
SET image32 = replace(image32, 'img', 'images/Products')
```

If 'img' was a directory, better search for '/img/' and replace it with '/images/Products/'.  You never know what filenames might contain img.

Comment: Wow I still have a long way to go to becoming a SQL Query master.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you did just answer your question.  You need to UPDATE if you want your data updated.  Table data only gets changed when you INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE.

Comment: Ok, cool.  Im gonna give this a shot on my own.  Thanks.  BTW - You guys are super quick!!  :)